# Leopard on a Lion Mac

Tags: mac, partitioning, osx-lion, boot-camp

I have a brand new Mac with OS X Lion on it.  I would like to have a 200 gig partition with Leopard on it (I have the discs).  When I insert the disc, upon bootup it just gives me a black screen with lots of white type.  At that point nothing happens, and typing does nothing.  Any ideas?  Do the new Lions just have everything put in place to not allow you to do anything except Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

New Macs are always locked to only working with the OS version they shipped with, or any later version.

Earlier versions of the OS don't have drivers for the I/O devices in your machine anyway, and there's not as much ability to download OS X drivers direct from the chipset manufacturers like you can often do with Windows.

You can't just take the [Mountain] Lion drivers and copy them onto Leopard and expect them to run, because they were developed and compiled against [Mountain] Lion-level APIs.

If you want to run an old version of OS X, you pretty much have to use an old Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN** install both Lion (10.7) & Leopard (10.5) on a single system.

- Im assuming your current OSX is Lion.
- Boot into it, and go to Disk Utility.
- Then click on your hard drive. (For Ex. 500.11GB Toshiba)
- Click on partition, and below the Partition Layout Diagram there are <kbd>+</kbd> & <kbd>-</kbd> buttons.
- Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button and make a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) partition and specify how much space you and to allocate to it.
- Reboot, with the Leopard DVD in the drive. Press <kbd>OPTION</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> key while booting, and select the Leopard installation disk to boot from.
- While installation, select the new partition you made to install Leopard.
- After installation is complete, you will have to press OPTION at boot every time around to select which OSX you want to boot from.

Other Stuff:

- BootCamp is only for Windows installations.
- I always install the new OSX this way, in parallel so i can try it out before i migrate.

Comment: I've tried this whole process already.  When I get to the point of booting the disk, it just gives me a black page with white type.  I've been told by a Mac employee that new Macs do not support anything except Lion and MountainLion, which is why booting the disk doesn't work.
I'm now trying to run a VirtualMachine, which also doesn't seem to recognize my Leopard disk, because there isn't an ISO image on it...
Frustrating...

Comment: Make an ISO out of that the Leopard disk. And well, did you call Mac Support and ask if it's true that new Macs don't run Leopard, or did you ask somebody? Coz for me it works. Give me your exact Mac Model. Wait, do you have a MacBook with Retina display?